# Prove that $|\sin x| \le 1$ and $|\cos x| \le 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How do we show that $|\sin x| \le 1$ and $|\cos x| \le 1$? After expanding them into their respective power series, how do we proceed further? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to use $\sin $ etc.

Comment: Is the power series your definition for the functions, then?

Comment: Yes I have assumed so.

Answer (score 2):

From $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ follows that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ can be in their absolute value at most 1...

Answer (score 2):

Show that $\sin^2 x + \cos ^2 x=1$.

That's a little messy to do directly from the power series, although not impossible.

An easier approach is to show that the derivative of $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$ is $0$, using results you can prove from the power series, that $\sin'(x)=\cos x$ and $\cos'(x)=-\sin x$.

Even easier if you know that the power series formulae yields  expressions for $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: So in other words I should replace $sin$ and $cos$ here with their power series?

Comment: "here"? Please be specific. @Paradox101 I've given you suggestions for two different approaches.

Comment: I meant do we replace the $sin$ and $cos$ with their power series in the identity you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: I mentioned several identities, but if you mean the first one, yes. You need to know how to square a power series.

Comment: Yes I can square a power series. Regarding the third approach you mentioned, how will that help show that $sin$ and $cos$ are bounded by $1$?

Comment: You can use those formula to also prove that $\cos^2 +\sin^2 =1$. @Paradox101 The second approach is probably the easiest and most self-contained.

Comment: Can I discuss this problem with you over chat? I still need to clear somethings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31321/discussion-between-paradox-101-and-thomas-andrews).

Comment: Sorry, at work. Seen no evidence of work on your part, BTW.